# Application vs Cache : Lock mechanism 

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, .net-4.0

The `Application` class in asp.net has `Lock` mechanism to support thread safety.

As we know - the `Application` can be accessed globally.

sample :

```
Application.Lock();
Application["MyCode"] = 21;
Application.UnLock();
```

ok.

**but**

Also the `Cache` is globally Accessible  ( and doesnt have lock mechanism and also used to remove/ add items)

so why does `Application` has a lock mechanism and `Cache` Doesn't ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Application` is a datastore remaining from old ASP technology. It has a single global lock. When you call `Application.Lock()` all accesses to Application object in all threads are blocked.

On the other hand the newer `Cache` object which was introduced with ASP.NET allows you to use your own locking semantics. You can use .NET's `lock` statement to ensure thread-safe access to Cache object while keeping your web application as parallel as possible. The `lock` statement is much safer since lock is guaranteed to be released when you exit a `lock` block. Application object doesn't guarantee that. Cache also provides auto-expire mechanisms which is much more suited for, well, a cache. It can also expire keys based on dependency contracts and optional priorities which of course Application object lacks.

I see no reason to use `Application` over `Cache` object.

Example: Let's say you have hundred items in the cache and you have a single item you want to store in the cache if it's not already there. When you use `Application`, you do this:

```
if(Application["someData"] == null) 
{
    Application.Lock();
    if(Application["someData"] == null) 
    {
        Application["someData"] = getValue(); //a very long time consuming function
    }
    Application.Unlock();
}
```

In this scenario all accesses to Application object are blocked even if they are completely irrelevant. And in case `getValue()` causes an exception your Application is hung because the lock is not released. You need to wrap a `try`..`finally` around that to make sure it's safe.

On the other hand when using a `Cache` object, you do this:

```
if(Cache["someData"] == null)
{
    lock(myLockObject)  // or other shared lock for that single value
    {
        if(Cache["someData"] == null)
        {
            Cache["someData"] = getValue();
        }
    }
}
```

In this case only code blocks which require access to `myLockObject` would be waiting. Others which access to `Cache` would be running in parallel just fine. And in case `getValue()` throws an exception your lock is released without any issues letting other threads continue execution.

Comment: The Cache collection was made thread-safe by Microsoft.  No external locking is required.

Comment: Cache itself being thread-safe only guarantees atomicity not consistency. Look at the example code above. If you don't have `lock` statement there multiple threads would be calling `getValue()` at the same time regardless cache is thread safe or not.

Comment: And I wonder the reason behind the downvote, stating "this answer is not useful". Really?

Comment: It's true that "getValue()" in your scenerio is not thread-safe so locking is required. But the OPs question is related to why the Cache collection itself doesn't have a Lock() method like the Application collection.  And the simple answer is because the Application collection is not thread-safe and the Cache collection is thread-safe.

Comment: You're wrong. It's there only for legacy compatibility with that old archaic programming model. Application itself is thread safe too. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate.aspx And it being "thread-safe" does not mean you cannot mess up consistency as I stated before.

Comment: If by 'consistency' you mean synchronized access, then I agree. And the Lock() and Unlock() methods I guess exist only from legacy and aren't really needed any longer.

Comment: How does that make my answer "not useful"? (which downvoting means)